# Condition in each function is outputting same set of results for all records

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, each

I am performing a `foreach` loop and then sending that data. Then in my AJAX function I am outputting the information in the success function. This all works fine.

However, I just tweaked the code to include a new `data-attribute`. This `data-attribute` holds the $creator variable. It can be seen here:

```
$html .= '<div class="projectCont" data-current="'.$category.'" data-creator="'.$project_creator.'">';
```

The correct data is outputting.

What I am having issues with is adding the active class to the container - `.projectCont` when the data-attribute - `data-creator` is customer.

Right now it seems like only the last looped object is being checked and then whatever this is, the rest of the data is taking on.

For example: I have around 10 looped object being outputted. For testing purposes, I changed the creator to "Customer" for only one of these - the last one in the database. Now when all of these loop and output, every single record has the class that was added based on my condition in the success.

Does anyone know why this is happening? I nested this condition in the each function thinking that it would check and modify each individual record.

Condition in question (see JS for more code):

```
var projectCreator = $('.projectCont').data('creator');
if (projectCreator == 'Customer') {
    $('.creatorIcon').addClass('active');
    console.log("It should be showing");
} else {
    $('.creatorIcon').removeClass('active');
}
```

JS:

```
success: function (data) {
  //console.log(data);
    if (data == null) {
        alert("Unable to retrieve projects!");
        alert(data);
    } else {
        var displayProjects = JSON.parse(data);
        $wrapper.empty();
        $(displayProjects).each(function() {
            $wrapper.append(this.html);
            //console.log(this.html);
            var projectCreator = $('.projectCont').data('creator');
            if (projectCreator == 'Customer') {
                $('.creatorIcon').addClass('active');
                console.log("It should be showing");
            } else {
                $('.creatorIcon').removeClass('active');
            }
        });
        $wrapper.append(startBuilding);
    }
```

PHP:

```
if ($projects_stmt = $con->prepare($projects_sql)) {
    $projects_stmt->execute();
    $project_rows = $projects_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $proj_arr = array();
    foreach ($project_rows as $project_row) {
        $project_creator = $project_row['creator'];
        $html = '';
        $html .= '<div class="projectCont" data-current="'.$category.'" data-creator="'.$project_creator.'">';
        $html .= '<div class="creatorIcon"><img src="/Projects/expand.png" alt="Customer Photo"></div>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $data = array('id' => $project_row['id'], 'date' => $project_row['date_added'], 'html' => $html);
        $proj_arr[] = $data;
    }
}
echo json_encode($proj_arr);
```

More JS:

```
$('.categoryList').on('click', function (event) {
        $('#projectsWrap').addClass('active'); //Once a category is selected the project wrap section will show
        $wrapper = $('#projectGallery');
        category = $(this).data('category');

        //console.log(category);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/php/projectLoadTest.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'category': category
            },
            success: function (data) {
              //console.log(data);
                if (data == null) {
                    alert("Unable to retrieve projects!");
                    alert(data);
                } else {
                    var displayProjects = JSON.parse(data);
                    $wrapper.empty();
                    $(displayProjects).each(function() {
                        $wrapper.append(this.html);
                        //console.log(this.html);
                        var projectCreator = $('.projectCont').data('creator');
                        if (projectCreator == 'Customer') {
                            $('.creatorIcon').addClass('active');
                            console.log("It should be showing");
                        } else {
                            $('.creatorIcon').removeClass('active');
                        }
                    });
                    $wrapper.append(startBuilding);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + " | " + errorThrown);
                alert('There are currently no project images for this selection');
            }
        });
        //was here
    });
```

Comment: there is probably more than one element that matches the `.projectCont` selector. you need to find a new way of targetting the relevant element instead of using a selector that will match many.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Would using the `$this` function instead be the trick to doing this? Awesome username btw.

Comment: i would need to see more code. i can't tell what context `this` would be in with what you've provided.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I added more JS to my question (at the bottom).

Comment: try using the event target... `var projectCreator = $(event.target).data('creator');` since `this` will refer to something else inside the success callback.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Thanks for your help. I ended up using the answer below. It works very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you shouldn't mess with the JS in this case - you can do this class manipulation in your PHP:

```
if ( $projects_stmt = $con->prepare( $projects_sql ) ) {

  $projects_stmt->execute();

  $project_rows = $projects_stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

  $proj_arr = array();

  foreach ( $project_rows as $project_row ) {

    $project_creator = $project_row[ 'creator' ];

    $html = '';

    $html .= '<div class="projectCont" data-current="' . $category . '" data-creator="' . $project_creator . '">';

    // setting the active string - if Customer -> ' active'
    $is_active = ( $project_creator == 'Customer' ) ? ' active' : '';

    $html .= '<div class="creatorIcon' . $is_active . '"><img src="/Projects/expand.png" alt="Customer Photo"></div>';

    $html .= '</div>';

    $data = array( 'id' => $project_row[ 'id' ], 'date' => $project_row[ 'date_added' ], 'html' => $html );

    $proj_arr[] = $data;

  } // foreach

} // if

echo json_encode( $proj_arr );
```

Comment: you should be assigning `$projects_stmt`, not comparing. single `=`. just like op had in his question.

Comment: I'm happy that I could help you out :)